# Angular 2 : Error while save file when npm server is running

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Getting this error while when save .ts or .html during npm is running

```
 1: DoJoin(aka DoJoin) [native array.js:~129] [pc=0000035BB365DBB2] 
(this=0000005A3F604381 <undefined>,w=000003CB8840CFF1 <JS 
Array[104]>,x=104,N=0000005A3F6043C1
 <true>,J=000000DB8B0DB361 <String[2]: , >,I=0000005A3F6B46F1 <JS Function 
ConvertToString (SharedFunctionInfo 0000005A3F652DC9)>)
2: Join(aka Join) [native array.js:180] [pc=0000035BB3A1FB52] 
(this=0000005A3F604381 <undefined...
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: what do you mean "while npm server is running"?  and where is this error happening?  angular only interacts with the browser, and doesn't have the ability to save html or ts files;  if you mean that you are getting an error when trying to *edit* the files, then knowing **exactly** what npm commands are running and what file editor you are using are minimum information necessary to understand the problem.

Comment: In my IDE while the server is running and i edit code and save that code,
this error is showing in console of IDE.

Comment: ok, **what IDE**?  and **what command are you running,** ***exactly***?.  angular doesn't care what is going on with the server; this is either a problem with your NPM script or your IDE, and you still have provided **Neither**.

Comment: I am using Visual Code IDE and command is 'npm start'

Comment: and `npm start` does what exactly?  are we talking about angular-cli?

Comment: yes, this issue is related to angular-cli

Answer (score 1):

If angular-cli lacks the heap you can increase it by changing the `ng.cmd` (or sh depending on which OS you are using) under `C:\Users\%userName%\AppData\Roaming\npm` like this:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=8048 "%~dp0\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node --max_old_space_size=8048 "%~dp0\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
)
```

(Paths may vary depending on your system)